# Printing only one element from webelement list in excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My code is to print a list of title in to excel using webelement list, but it is only printing one that is last data in to excel. please help.

```
            driver.get("http://www.speakingcs.com/");
                Sheet sh;
            List<WebElement> postTitles = driver.findElements(By.className("entry-header"));
        for (WebElement eachTitle:postTitles)
        {
            System.out.println(eachTitle.getText());
                File object = new File("D:/selenium/data.xlsx");
                    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(object);
                     wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
                     sh=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
                    Row row=null;
                    if(sh.getRow(0) != null) {
                            row = sh.getRow(0);}
                        else {
                            row = sh.createRow(0);
                        }

                       Cell cell=row.createCell(0);
                    cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                   
                    cell.setCellValue(eachTitle.getText());

             for(int m=1; m<6; m++)

         sh.autoSizeColumn(m);
             }
                        FileOutputStream fos=new     FileOutputStream("D:/selenium/data.xlsx");
                        wb.write(fos);
                        fos.close();
                        System.out.println("test1");

             }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }

this is printing only last title whereas 5 are there.
```

no error is there.try catch is added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you overwrite your excel sheet for every `WebElement` that you are processing and always overwriting the first row in that sheet instead of creating a new row. Try creating a new row for each element, like this:

```
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

List<WebElement> postTitles = driver.findElements(By.className("entry-header"));
for (int index = 0; index <= postTitles.size(); index++) {
    WebElement eachTitle = postTitles.get(index);

    Row row = null;
    if (sh.getRow(index) != null) {
        row = sh.getRow(index);
    } else {
        row = sh.createRow(index);
    }
  ...
}
```