# Error printing list of values in excel using selenium and java for a shopping website. Prints only first value

Tags: java, excel, selenium

[output on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjPyM.png)

[Prompt on opening excel after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzeNG.png)

[output in excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYiP.png)

I am trying to get top few results from a shopping website(flipkart), I am able to get the results in my compiler but they won't print in the excel. Every time only the first value is printed and the rest is blank. I am trying to print a product's name and it's href link. Again no issue printing in compiler using sysout. With this code only one name of the first element is shown in excel and no links.
the link to the website's direct page which I am using is : https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D30000&sort=recency_desc

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\selenium\\qwertyuiop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D30000&sort=recency_desc");
      
   OutputStream inStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\hp\\eclipse-workspace\\firstselenium\\data\\test.xlsx"); 

       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
   
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new"); 
       XSSFRow row;
       XSSFCell cell;
       
       
       //=sheet.createRow(0);
       List<WebElement> xpaths=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3wU53n']"));
       List<WebElement> xpathsLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_31qSD5']"));
       
       int a=0;
           System.out.println("number of elements: " + xpaths.size()); 
           for(WebElement ele : xpaths){ 
               //ele.sendKeys("value"); 
               
                row = sheet.createRow(0);
               cell = row.createCell(0);
           //  a++;
               cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
               wb.write(inStream);
               //a++;
               //System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
                
             
           }  
           for(WebElement ele : xpathsLink){ 
               row = sheet.createRow(a);
               cell = row.createCell(1); 
               cell.setCellValue(ele.getAttribute("href"));
               wb.write(inStream);
               a++;
               //System.out.println(ele.getText());
           System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));}
```

Comment: Can you share the output on console and excel

Comment: Just shared, please check

Comment: You can refer to this question
it is quite similar to yours ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819888/printing-only-one-element-from-webelement-list-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

this code has been updated and works fine for printing elements using loop in an excel file. Issue is to print more details in the cells. For instance printing product name, href link, and details in the same row but obviously different cells.
To clear the error to print in different rows using loop state the wb.write() command outside the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\selenium\\qwertyuiop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D30000&sort=recency_desc");
      
   OutputStream inStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\hp\\eclipse-workspace\\firstselenium\\data\\test.xlsx"); 

       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
   
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new"); 
       XSSFRow row;
       XSSFCell cell;
       
           
List<WebElement> xpaths=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3wU53n']"));
            List<WebElement> productPoperties=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3ULzGw']")); 
             List<WebElement> xpathsLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_31qSD5']"));    
              int c=0;
              int o=5;
              int m=5;
            int b=0;
            int a=0;
            int n=5;
          System.out.println("number of elements: " + xpaths.size()); 
          
          for(WebElement ele : xpaths){ 
             row = sheet.createRow(a);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            a++;
            cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
            System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
            n--;
               if(n==0)break;
          }  
        // wb.write(inStream);
            
          for(WebElement ele : productPoperties){ 
              //ele.sendKeys("value"); 
            
             row = sheet.createRow(b);
            cell = row.createCell(5);
            b++;
            cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
//          wb.write(inStream);
            //a++;
            System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
            m--;
               if(m==0)break;
            
          }
         // wb.write()
         
          for(WebElement ele : xpathsLink){ 
                row = sheet.createRow(c);
                cell = row.createCell(8); 
                a++;
                cell.setCellValue(ele.getAttribute("href"));
            //  wb.write(inStream);
                c++;
                //System.out.println(ele.getText());
              System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));
              o--;
              if(o==0)break;
              }

          wb.write(inStream);
```

see whether it works

Comment: I had tried this already, the same is there for the second loop but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please just write wb.write(inStream) after the for loop end. Then text will be fetched from all the elements.

```
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D30000&sort=recency_desc");
    OutputStream inStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\hp\\eclipse-workspace\\firstselenium\\data\\test.xlsx"); 
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new"); 
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
   
   List<WebElement> xpaths=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3wU53n']"));
   List<WebElement> xpathsLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_31qSD5']"));
   
   int a=0;
   System.out.println("number of elements: " + xpaths.size());            
   for(WebElement ele : xpaths){ 
         
              row = sheet.createRow(a);
              cell = row.createCell(0);
              cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
              a++;
              System.out.println(ele.getText());               
             
   }  
   for(WebElement ele : xpathsLink){ 
               row = sheet.createRow(a);
               cell = row.createCell(1); 
               cell.setCellValue(ele.getAttribute("href"));
               a++;
               System.out.println(ele.getText());
               System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));
   }
   wb.write(inStream);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Finally!!

Comment: Hey, how do I add multiple data in the same row different cells? It looks like I should not create a row everytime ? Please help. I have updated the code.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is helpful for you. And regarding the second requirement (add multiple data in the same row, I am looking into this).

Comment: Yes it was helpful. Please share if you find a solution to print multiple data in same row.

Comment: Hey, I found the way. In the first loop you mention create row but in the next ones you use getRow() instead of createRow()

Comment: Yes. Great! its working now. But you don't need any other variables (m, n, o) to perform this task. Just need to use getRow() instead of createRow().

Comment: I have those to iterate it in order to get 5 products and not the whole range of 24 from one page

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<WebElement> productName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3wU53n']"));
            List<WebElement> productPoperties=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3ULzGw']")); 
            List<WebElement> productLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_31qSD5']"));    
              int c=0;
              int o=5;
              int m=5;
              int b=0;
              int a=0;
              int n=5;
             
          
          for(WebElement ele : productName){ 
             row = sheet.createRow(a);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            a++;
            cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
            System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
            n--;
               if(n==0)break;
          }  
          
          for(WebElement ele : productPoperties){   
             row = sheet.getRow(b);
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            b++;
            cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
            System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
            m--;
               if(m==0)break;
            
          }
          
          for(WebElement ele : productLink){ 
                row = sheet.getRow(c);
                cell = row.createCell(8); 
                cell.setCellValue(ele.getAttribute("href"));
                c++;
              System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));
              o--;
              if(o==0)break;
              }

          wb.write(inStream);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the final code:

```
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=CLP_Filters&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p%5B%5D=facets.price_range.to%3D30000&sort=recency_desc");
    OutputStream inStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/arpita/Arpita/flipkartProductsName2.xlsx"); 
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new"); 
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
   
    List<WebElement> productName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3wU53n']"));
    List<WebElement> productPoperties=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3ULzGw']")); 
    List<WebElement> productLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_31qSD5']"));    
     
    int c=0;
    int b=0;
    int a=0;
    
    System.out.println("number of elements: " + productName.size()); 
     
  
  for(WebElement ele : productName){ 
    row = sheet.createRow(a);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    a++;
    cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
    System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
  
  }  
  
  for(WebElement ele : productPoperties){   
    row = sheet.getRow(b);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    b++;
    cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
    System.out.println(ele.getText()); 
  
    
  }
  
  for(WebElement ele : productLink){ 
        row = sheet.getRow(c);
        cell = row.createCell(2); 
        cell.setCellValue(ele.getAttribute("href"));
        c++;
      System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));
   
  }

  wb.write(inStream);
```